# Guaranteed atomic move of folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that runs every minute at XX:00. The script loops over all subfolders in a given directory and performs operations on the files inside;

```
folder=/path/to/directory #Starting directory
someerror=0 #Did we have an error?

#CD to directory. Does it even exist?
cd $folder
RETVAL=$?
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && echo Success changing directory to $folder && mainfolderexist=1
[ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] && echo Failure changing directory to $folder && mainfolderexist=0

if [ $mainfolderexist -eq 1 ]; then
    shopt -s nullglob
    for dir in $folder/*/
    do
    thedirname=`basename $dir` #Get directory name
    #cd to sub dir. Does it even exist?
    cd $dir
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && echo Success changing directory to $dir && subfolderexist=1
    [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] && echo Failure changing directory to $dir && subfolderexist=0
    if [ $subfolderexist -eq 1 ]; then
        #perform some operation on all files in this directory
        someApp -someArgs --name=$thedirname *
    else #sub folder doesn't exist
        someerror=1
        break
    fi

    #next folder
    done
else #main folder doesn't exist
    someerror=1
fi

#REPEAT (only if no errors occured)
if [ $someerror -eq 0 ]; then
at now + 1 minutes << END
/bin/bash "$0" "$@"
END
fi
```

The way I use this, is I upload directories to the server using SFTP, to a folder like `/home/incoming`, and once the directory is fully uploaded I will move it to `/path/to/directory`. Now this is the part I am worried about.

So far I've been making sure to only move directories between XX:XX:02 and XX:XX:50, but is this even neccesary? I would like to automate the upload+move process without taking system time into account so I am wondering;

1. What if a directory is in the process of getting moved (`mv "somedir" "/path/to/directory/somedir"`) at XX:00 and the script runs, looping over all directories?
2. What if the system loses power during the mv command? If the directory will end up half moved or something similar, I will have to write a script verifying this before executing the above script.

Comment: This is a bit orthogonal to your question, but how do you know when the directory is "fully uploaded"?

Comment: Do you know whether your source and destination are on the same filesystem?  If not, you may need to add some intelligence to your cron job to cause it not to touch directories that are only partially copied.

Comment: @larsks I don't, that's why I am doing it manually right now. I intend to write a program that lets the server know what to expect from a directory, start uploading, and move said directory when the expectation matches the real deal. Or something like that.. unless you have a better alternative?

Comment: If you upload archives (using tar or zip or something) instead of directories, you can use something like [inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) to trigger events when the upload is complete...but this only works for individual files.  Using directories, you could accomplish the same thing with a flag file (that is, after the directory upload is complete, create a `<directory>.finished` file or something).  This might actually be a good idea even if you don't opt for something like `inotify` (your script can just look for the `.finished` files).

Comment: @larsks: Using just inotify with archives has the disadvantage, that if the connection breaks, it will be reported as close by inotify, so you still need some mean of checking that the archive is indeed complete. That's easy with zip, not so much with other formats like tar or gz. Renaming the uploaded data at the end, by the upload process, is safest option.

Comment: That's true, although using a flag file also solves this problem.  If you can trivially rename files that's certainly the best option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your source and destination paths are on the same filesystem, then `mv` is an atomic operation. Since it does not actually involve copying or otherwise relocating files, your directories will never end up in a "half-moved" state.

If, on the other hand, your source and destination paths are on *different* filesystems, then `mv` is actually a copy followed by a delete over the entire tree, which can take a substantial amount of time and, if interrupted, will leave things in a half-completed state.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to tell mv to fail if the source and destination are not on the same filesystem, so you have to make sure you set it up right.

Comment: Assuming Linux, You can use the `mountpoint` command to determine if the two paths are on the same filesystem or not prior to calling `mv`, but I suspect there's no point in this case -- presumably the destination path is fixed so there's no need to check every time.

Comment: How about if I run `ls -s >> /home/folder_expectation/$thedirname_source` on the source directory, prior to executing the mv command. And then every loop in my main script, I run `ls -s >> /home/folder_expectation/$thedirname_target`, and then `cmp /home/folder_expectation/$thedirname_source /home/folder_expectation/$thedirname_target`. After which it will break the loop (or skip the current item) if it doesn't match. Would this work cross-filesystem?

Comment: It might be interesting nowadays that the [OSX mv](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mv.1.html) doesn't call rename at all! So I think bash scripts might behave differently on OSX but look the same.

Comment: You run into this stuff a lot when dealing with NFS. A cheap way to workaround it is to copy your file/dir to a temporary location on the same filesystem, then do a `mv`, which will be atomic. e.g.
`TMP="temp.$RANDOM" && cp -a mydir /dest/dir/$TMP && mv /dest/dir/$TMP /dest/dir/mydir`

Answer (score 4):

I believe that `mv` is an atomic operation (moving a directory just renames the directory, it doesn't move any files on disk).  `mv` makes the sys-call `rename` which according to [this](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/rename.2.php) is atomic (subject to some constraints).

> If newpath already exists it will be atomically replaced (subject to a few conditions - see ERRORS below), so that there is no point at which another process attempting to access newpath will find it missing.

Comment: The problem is when it isn't using rename. If you are still around, could you mention that somewhere in your post? Of course the marked answer already says that, but just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the movement is not atomic even if you are in the same disc and partition when either one (or both) is using encryption as a software. Eg: 2 users in the same machine have directories in the /home. If one of then uses an encrypted home directory, the move will not be atomic because it will need to encrypt/decrypt or decrypt/encrypt or encrypt or decrypt the files before make the move